# Cover $ 7 \times 7$ chessboard with $\sqrt 2$ diameter coins

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math, puzzle

What is the minimum number of coins of diameter $\sqrt 2$ needed to cover a $ 7 \times 7$ chessboard (made up of squares of length $1$) in such a way that each square contains at least one point covered by a coin ?

Piecemeal speaking the best you can do is intersect $6$ squares with one such coin, but this method leaves the margin of the board untouched.

Any ideas ?

Comment: @Arthur one coin will cover 6 squares...

Comment: The question is **not** about covering, despite the title. Not sure what is the proper term for it; "touching", maybe?

Comment: It seems to me you can interesect $7$ squares, not $6$, with a single coin:  Start by placing a coin exactly at the center of a square, so it covers that square entirely and overlaps with the $4$ squares above and below it and to its right and left.  Then shift it down by a small amount, to pick up points inside $2$ additional squares diagonally below it.

Comment: Are the squares/coins open or closed?  Wouldn't a coin in the centre of a square entirely contain that square, and thus cover at least one point from each of the eight surrounding squares?

Comment: Barry Cipra, how would you make the seven squre groups fit together ? It seems you'd need at least two shapes.

Comment: @argh1997, what you say (in your comment) is quite correct.  I wasn't giving an answer, just pointing out that your observation about $6$ being "the best you can do" wasn't correct.  (Incidentally, if you respond with an "@" in front of my name, it will ping me; I only saw your comment just now because Parcly Taxel's answer brought the problem back to the front page.)

Comment: @Shagnik, I wondered the same myself.  But as Parcly Taxel's answer shows, it doesn't matter in the end, you still need $9$ coins (because $\sqrt2$ is *strictly* less than $2$).

Answer (score 3):

Note that one coin can cover **at most three** consecutive squares, simply because its diameter is between 1 and 2. In other words, the squares touched by a single coin fall within a 3-by-3 bounding box.

Now consider the four corner squares, the middle squares on each side and the centre square of the chessboard:

```
*..*..*
.......
.......
*..*..*
.......
.......
*..*..*
```

A 3-by-3 box can cover at most one of these squares (marked by * above). Hence we need at least nine boxes, or coins, to cover every square of the board, which is also an upper bound:

```
1118877
1118877
2228877
2220666
3344666
3344555
3344555
```

where blocks of the same digit indicate the squares covered by one coin. Hence the answer to the original question is 9.